# How do you take the Laplace transform of a mass spring damper system when the spring is a progressive spring?

Tags: laplace-transform

A simple mass-spring-damper system is pretty simple. The differential equation can be simply written below:

$$
F= m \frac{d^2x}{dt^2} + b \frac{dx}{dt} + k x(t)
$$

which is transformed via LaPlace to:

$$
\frac{F}{s}=x(s)(ms^2+bs+k)
$$

Finding the damping value that makes the system critically damped is simple:

$$
s = \frac{-b ±\sqrt{b^2-4mk}}{2m}  
$$

therefore the system is critically damped when:

$b=\sqrt{4mk}$

Changing the spring to a progressive spring, the origional formula changes to:

$$
F= m \frac{d^2x}{dt^2} + b \frac{dx}{dt} + k x(t)^2.
$$

How does the Laplace transform change from this and how does that effect the damping coefficient for critical damping?

Comment: It's "Laplace", not "LaPlace"

Comment: You’ve simplified away unstated initial conditions, and the Laplace transform of $x^2$ introduces a challenging relationship to that of $x$.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about critically damped or expression for Laplace tranform without convolution in $s$ domain. But here is a way to  obtain an analytic solution for $x(t)$.

The equation you want to solve for progressive spring case is not linear. So $e^{sx}$ is no longer an eigen function. I suggest you try to assume $x(t) = \sum_i a_i (t-r)^i$ i.e., $x(t)$ is analytic and solve for the equation $0=m\frac{d^2x}{dt^2} + b \frac{dx}{dt} + k * x(t)^2$.

The equation is
$$\sum_{i\geq 2} m i(i-1) \times a_i \times (t-r)^{i-2}+\sum_{i\geq 1} bi \times a_i \times (t-r)^{i-1} + \sum_{i \geq 0} k \times \left(\sum_{k=0}^i a_{i-k} a_k \right) \times(t-r)^i  = 0$$

Comparing coefficients of $(t-r)^0$, this will give $2ma_2 + b a_1 + k a_0^2 = 0$.

Comparing coefficients of $(t-r)^1$, this will give $6ma_3 + 2b a_2 + k (a_0a_1+a_1a_0) = 0$.

Comparing coefficients of $(t-r)^i$, this will give $$(i+2)(i+1)m a_{i+2} + (i+1)b a_{i+1} + k \left(\sum_{k=0}^i a_{i-k} a_k \right) = 0$$.

Start by assigning some value for $a_1,a_0$ and back solve to get a solution for $x(t)$. Although it seems there exists a solution if you solve like this, Not sure if its a useful solution for your purpose.

Note that $a_0 = x(r)$ and $a_1 = x'(r)$ which are exactly boundary conditions. You can assume $r=0$ for a solution near $t=0$. Note that the solution has a region of convergence and works only in an open interval around $r$. If you want solution for general analytic $F$, then replace the RHS with $b_i$ where $F = \sum_i b_i (t-r)^i$. Technically the last point is the usual trouble. You can only solve for $F$ which is analytic in an open interval around $r$.